# Can I upgrade my Soltek sl-67a-c motherboard from Pentium II to Pentium III?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a Pentium III processor and I thought I would replace the Pentium II on my Soltek SL-67A-C.  The motherboard has Slot 1 so the PIII fits in fine, however, when I turn on the computer the bios does not come up.

Here's the link to some specs on the board:
http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/F/FLASH-TECH-INC-Pentium-II-Deschutes-SL-67A-C.html

I know that I updated the bios at one time.  I see references to a "67af3.zip" bios upgrade file out there but can't find any source to download it.

I am thinking I may have to adjust the jumpers on the motherboard to match the speed of the processor, but I am not sure how to go about that.

Any suggestions?

EDITED:
I guess another name for the motherboard is Intel 82440LX

Comment: That manual says Pentium II, and nothing about Pentium III. What makes you think it will work? It was very specific as to what processor it will take, and just because another one fits, doesn't mean anything. Unless you have some other documentation that supersedes what you posted, it is not going to work.

Comment: I knew it was Slot 1; I searched for "sl-67a-c pentium III" and found results like this http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/66501,soltek-sl-67a-bios-1-03-f/ which led me to think it would work.

Comment: I understand now, but you really need to look at the board and determine what revision yours is. Often one version supports certain processors, and then a later revision supports newer processors. If your board is older, based on your latest link, it may support it, but that is no guarantee even if you flash the BIOS.

Comment: There's a point at which you might need to look into getting new hardware. That point was about 5 years ago. =)

Comment: @tjameson Yeah, I paid $3,000 for it in 1997 and ran it continuously for the next 13 years.  I got my money's worth but I'm also attached.  When the SCSI drive finally died, I thought I might upgrade it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the [440bx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_1#Intel_440BX_.5B8.5D) on that motherboard *should* support a Pentium III chip with slot 1 according to Wikipedia - though I suppose the BIOS would need to support it as well. At the age of the system though, its more a curiosity than anything else, and finding documentation will be a pain.

The Wikipedia article DOES mention the Pentium II and III options run at different FSBs. However, without the manual (or some very careful peering at the motherboard) it will be rather hard to tell what you can do about it.

Comment: I finally found the manual that came with the custom built computer, but it seems like it may be the wrong one.  It refers to Intel 82440LX.  However, as you noted the online documentation says the sl-67a-c has the 440BX chipset.  The LX doesn't support Pentium III but the BX does.  Is there any way to determine the chipset by looking at the board?  I think the relevant chip has a heat sink glued to it so I might be unable to find out for sure.

Comment: if you can boot into it, lshw in linux or some similar utility - say device manager for whatever flavour of windows you're running might help.